# JQuery option value sometimes undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having trouble with a simple select-option.
Most of the time the selected-value (in the action var) yields the correct result ("closed") but sometimes it is "undefined".

```
$("#doaction").click(function () {
  // action sometimes is "undefined" =>
  var action = $("#workflow option:selected").val();        
}
```

---

```
<select name="workflow" id="workflow">
  <option value="-1">initial state</option>
  <option value="close">perform action close</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="doaction">submit</a>
```

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just:

```
$("#workflow").val()
```

The [val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will return the current selected option of a select element.

---

Using

```
$("#workflow option:selected").val()
```

is equivalent to

```
$("#workflow").val()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
$("#workflow").val();
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)